# os.walk working differently with input() vs hard-coded path

Tags: python, path, os.walk

```
import os

path = input()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    print (files)
```

works if I give as input -> c:\data

but not if:

```
import os

# hard-coded will only work if I use / instead of \
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\data', topdown=True):
    print (files)
```

Can someone explain me the reason for this behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: change `'c:\data'` to `r'c:\data'`, then give a try, it should work fine. [Python literal](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Comment: Curiously, "\d" isn't a valid escape sequence, so python should still be treating it as the 2 characters. Did your real case start with a different letter?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy it was actually c:\ton\data

Comment: @SJPRO, right, so \t is interpreted as a tab character. If anyone is interested, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Yeah, now I get it, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in literal strings, `\` is an escape character - allow putting quotes/tabs/newlines etc. in literal strings.

You should use `'c:\\data'` or `'c:/data'` (forward slash works fine in windows)

Another way is to use "raw" strings `r'c:\data'` but be careful, because you can't use any escaped characters anymore

Comment: That shouldn't matter here. `\d` isn't a recognized escape character, so Python "helpfully" pretends it's not an escape (I put sarcasm quotes around "helpfully", because when `'c:\data'` works, it gives the mistaken impression that raw strings aren't needed, leading to confusion when `'c:\bin'` fails, because `\b` becomes the ASCII backspace character). If I enter `'c:\data'` in the interactive interpreter, it echoes `'c:\\data'` as expected.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yes I have been caught by the same helpful feature in the past. OP clarified that it was actually a \t combo